# Making table Join Problem?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2000

Having Two Tables

Table1

```
Date ID

20090101 001
20090102 001
….
20090101 002
20090102 002
…

20090101 003
20090102 003
…
```

So on..,

Table2

```
ID Name Date

001 Raja 20090408
001 Raja 20090502
001 Raja 20090503
002 Ravi 20090312
002 Ravi 20090522
003 Saga 20090802
003 Saga 20091022
```

So on..,

Query

```
SELECT
   Table1.Date, Table1.ID, 
   Table2.Name, Table2.Date 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
ORDER BY table1.id, table1.date
```

Output

```
Date ID Name Table2.Date

20090101 001 Raja 20090408
20090101 001 Raja 20090502
20090101 001 Raja 20090503
20090102 001 Raja 20090408
20090102 001 Raja 20090502
20090102 001 Raja 20090503
…

20090101 002 Ravi 20090312
20090101 002 Ravi 20090522
20090102 002 Ravi 20090312
20090102 002 Ravi 20090522
…
```

So on…,

Why am getting a table1.date again and again. I want to display like this.

Expected Output

```
Date ID Name Table2.Date

20090101 001 Raja   - 
…
20090502 001 Raja 20090502
20090503 001 Raja 20090503
…
20090107 001 Raja   -
20090108 001 Raja 20090408
….
```

So on…,

I put "–" instead of Null Column

```
Table2.Date should equal to Table1.Date, means 
Table1.Date, Table1.ID should display all the columns, 
Table2.Date should display with Table1.Date Related column.
```

Example.

```
Table2 Column Values are

Date - 20090203, 20090205...,

Table1.ID Table1.Date Table2.Date

001 20090201 
001 20090202 
001 20090203 20090203
001 20090204
001 20090205 20090205
001 20090206 

...,
```

Before I make a query in Access 2003

```
SELECT AllPossibleCardEvents.Id,  AllPossibleCardEvents.Date, Actual.Date AS Table2Date FROM ((SELECT p.Id,  AllDates.Date FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM table2) AllDates, table1  p) AllPossibleCardEvents LEFT OUTER JOIN table2  Actual ON AllPossibleCardEvents.Id = Actual.Id AND AllPossibleCardEvents.tDate = Actual.Date) )
```

Now the above query is working perfectly for my expected output in access

How to make a Sql query for this condition?

Need Query Help

Comment: Am getting table1.date related to table2.Date column only by using left join, I need Table1.Date, Table1.ID should display all the columns, Table2.Date should display with Table1.Date Related columns .

Comment: I translated your access query to sqlserver, can you tell if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AllPossibleCardEvents.Date, 
       AllPossibleCardEvents.ID, 
       COALESCE(Table2.Date, '-') Table2Date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t2.Date 
        FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2) AllPossibleCardEvents
     LEFT JOIN table2 ON AllPossibleCardEvents.ID = table2.ID 
                     AND AllPossibleCardEvents.Date = table2.Date
ORDER BY AllPossibleCardEvents.ID, AllPossibleCardEvents.Date
```

Comment: Why the overkill?  You could just say ISNULL(Table2.Name, '-') instead of embeding the cases

Comment: Am not asking about null column, I need Table1.Date, Table1.ID should display all the columns, Table2.Date should display with Table1.Date Related column Now am getting table1.date related to table2.Date column only.

Comment: @Jabezz, ISNULL is not ANSI 92 compliant, so portability is an issue, and does not respect the rules of data type precedence, unlike CASE WHEN and COALESCE. I'll use COALESCE.

Comment: @najmeddine - Is working thank You, I forgot to try this in sql server.

Answer (score 4):

By the looks of it, all you are missing is to join the date columns as well:

```
Select 
  Table1.Date, Table1.ID, Table2.Name, Table2.Date 
from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.date = table2.date
order by table1.id, table1.date
```

This is if I understood your question correctly.

If you want to display the NULL values, you need to change to a LEFT join though:

```
Select 
  Table1.Date, Table1.ID, Table2.Name, Table2.Date 
from table1 
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.date = table2.date
order by table1.id, table1.date
```

EXTRA:

I've added some extra sql that might give you equivalent results to your Access query.
If I understand the Access query correctly, you are matching up all records, but only displaying table2.Date when it matches up with table1.Date.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    table1.Id,
    table1.Date,
    CASE WHEN table1.Date = table2.Date THEN table2.Date ELSE '-' END AS Table2Date
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2
```

If this is still not what you are looking for, I don't think I understand your questions at all.

Comment: Right.  You have non-normalized tables.  Garbage in, garbage out.  The problem isn't your query, it is your database design.

Comment: Now am getting table1.date related to table2.Date column only. I need Table1.Date, Table1.ID should display all the columns, 
Table2.Date should display with Table1.Date Related column

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the problem you are having. The answers given should give you the results as described in your question under Expected Output.

Comment: I Make a Example, see my question

Comment: @Gopal you seem to be totally moving away from your original question. How did a SQL Server 2000 question end up being, translate my Access query to give different results?  I have added an Access translation above, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you have non-existing values in `table2`, you need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. The INNER JOIN by design will *only* shows rows where both tables have values, e.g. it will filter out anything that doesn't exist in `table2`. Also, you're not joining on the "date" - that's why you get so many more result rows than expected.

Second, if you want to display something else than NULL for the non-existing values in `table2`, you need to use `ISNULL` to specify what to display instead of NULL:

```
SELECT
   Table1.Date, Table1.ID, Table2.Date
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   table2 ON table1.id = table2.id AND table1.date = table2.date
ORDER BY table1.id, table1.date
```

I get output something like this:

```
table1.Date                 table1.ID    table2.Date
2009-01-01 00:00:00.000        1            NULL
2009-01-02 00:00:00.000        1            NULL
2009-02-03 00:00:00.000        1            NULL
2009-02-05 00:00:00.000        1            NULL
2009-04-08 00:00:00.000        1         2009-04-08 00:00:00.000
2009-05-03 00:00:00.000        1         2009-05-03 00:00:00.000
2009-01-01 00:00:00.000        2            NULL
2009-01-02 00:00:00.000        2            NULL
2009-01-01 00:00:00.000        3            NULL
2009-01-02 00:00:00.000        3            NULL
```

Please clarify what is not good with this output....

Marc

Comment: Am not asking about null column, I need Table1.Date, Table1.ID should display all the columns, Table2.Date should display with Table1.Date Related column Now am getting table1.date related to table2.Date column only.

Comment: I want to display all the Dates, personid from the first table, dates from the second table which is related to first table.

Comment: I Make a Example, see my question

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what my query should output - what's not working with my query??

Comment: My Output is Table1.Date, ID, Table2.Date 10/16/2008 AEAA00294 20081016, 10/16/2008 AEAA00294 -----, 10/15/2008 AEAA00294 20081015, 10/15/2008 AEAA00294 -----, 10/14/2008 AEAA00294 20081014, 10/14/2008 AEAA00294 -----, 10/13/2008 AEAA00294 20081013, 10/13/2008 AEAA00294 -----, 10/12/2008 AEAA00294 -----, 10/11/2008 AEAA00294 -----, 10/10/2008 AEAA00294 -----, 
Why am getting Table1.Date two times what is the problem,

Comment: check out the data in your tables - you must be having something in there twice or even multiple times. The query will work just fine - if the data is bad, then the results will be bad, too......

Comment: Table1 Date Datatype is Date, Table2 Date Datatype is varchar. Is making a problem

Comment: Show us the output from  `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID = 'AEAA00294'` and the same for table2